# Running a shell script which runs a Java program

Tags: java, shell

I have a java application and from that application I want to be able to run new applications. While the concept is the same, I'm using this in a Minecraft environment where I want to have one application be able to run other Minecraft servers whenever I specify so in the first application.

I'm trying to run the startup shell script but whenever I do I simply get the error **Error: Unable to access jarfile server.jar**.

Note that I am perfectly able to run the script on my computer by "*double clicking it*", the shell script works, Java application starts up, and I can join the game server and play without any problems.

I've also tried running the jar application directly from the code, but then I get either **CreatProcess error=5** or **CreatProcess error=193** (using ProcessBuilder), even though I've set all the computer to have all permissions regarding reading and writing the file.

This is my code for running the shell script:

```java
// Starts the server by running the script
File startScript = new File("C:\\Users\\{MYUSER}\\Desktop\\{PROJECTNAME_FOLDER}\\Network\\prison-spawn-2\\start.bat");

// Run the process
try {
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start " + startScript.getCanonicalPath());

    int exitVal = process.waitFor();
    if (exitVal == 0) {
        System.out.println("Success!");
    }
} catch (Exception exception) {
    exception.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Batch Script Content**

```
echo "Starting server..."

java -jar C:\Users\{MYUSER}\Desktop\{PROJECTNAME_FOLDER}\Network\prison-spawn-2\server.jar nogui
```

Comment: Can you run file `RUN.bat` from a command prompt window (with the same user that you run the Java code) ? Also, the "command" string that you pass to method `exec` only needs to be the path to `RUN.bat`, i.e. `batchFile.getAbsolutePath()`. The operating system knows how to execute that file.

Comment: @Abra Running it from a command prompt works without problems and the server starts up. I also swapped the command string as you said, but that simply timed me out (and performed no actions) so had to change back to the "longer" command string

Comment: _the server starts up_ How do you know that the server starts up? _simply timed me out_ What happens that tells you that a timeout has occurred? Perhaps you can post a [mcve] because if I can't reproduce your problem, it's difficult to find the cause.

Comment: You're not processing stderr, which is quite wrong. And use ```ProcessBuilder``` which will make doing that (and more) easier

Comment: @Abra As I'm using this in a game environment, I know that it starts up because I can join the game server (in this case the Minecraft server) and play it. I can also see in the console how the game started up.

The game server shut down and said "Timeout", that's how I know I timed out. But I fixed that part specifically, that was just me being dum.

I switched it to a shell script and added some text printing, and the texts prints fine but as soon as it gets to the jar startup, it immediately goes back to **Error: Unable to access jarfile**

Comment: @g00se I tried using `ProcessBuilder` (and did before as well), but I then get a mix of new fancy errors with the latest one being `CreatProcess error=2 (cannot find file)`, even though the path (and the entire command) is the exact same as in the `#getRuntime().exec()` code

Comment: There's not really enough information. Also it doesn't inspire confidence that the file is called 'start.sh' ('.sh' normally a *Unix* shell script extension)

Comment: @g00se What do you want me to call the file instead then?

Comment: It doesn't matter what it's called ;) What does matter is if you're trying to run a bash shell script on Windows. I don't know if you are or not, because you haven't shown the content of that file. What's more, you haven't shown the value of ```startScript```

Comment: @g00se Ah I see, my bad! I've updated my post to add the contents of the shell script. The value of startScript returns `..\prison-spawn-2\start.sh` if that is what you mean?

Comment: Why are you mixing `/bin/sh` (shell script) and `cmd.exe` (ProcessBuilder)? I doubt any system will have both installed

Comment: @knittl Well mostly because working with shell scripts (nor how to run them from code) before. What solution do you recommend I go for instead?

Comment: @Liam I don't understand. Are you running this on a Linux or Windows system? Linux has `/bin/sh`, Windows has `cmd.exe`. But Linux does not have `cmd.exe` and Windows does not have `/bin/sh`. So starting `cmd.exe` from a shell script is going to fail. Running a shell script on Windows will fail too. Pick one system and stick to it.

Comment: @knittl Currently running this on Windows. It will run on Linux later in production, but it's Windows for now. As said, I've not worked with shell scripts before and I'm currently trying to learn, sorry for the inconvenience.

What do you mean by "*Running a shell script on Windows will fail too*"? Because I can certainly run a shell script on my computer to start up the game server (the server.jar application). What I can't, is having another java application run the script through code

Comment: OK. You've given me the value. Now we need the content of the file. If by some fluke the contents of that file are platform-neutral, it *could* work. But please don't treat .sh and .bat files as interchangeable. They are for different operating systems

Comment: @g00se When you say content of the file, you mean content of the shell script? If so I've added that to my post.

Alright I see what you mean with not treating the files as interchangeable. Actually didn't know that until now, does that mean you think I should go back to using batch instead while on the Windows machine?

Comment: Ah right, I missed the contents. If you get rid of the ```sleep```  calls and the first line, you can, (and should) rename that as 'start.bat'

Comment: @g00se Alright I did the changes and ran the program. The application runs the batch file, the batch file sends "Starting server", but then again gives me the "`Unable to access jarfile`" error.

This is what I first tried before swapping my batch script to a shell script (as I thought trying with something would give a new outcome). But I'm pretty sure that I'm just back where I started now?

Comment: server.jar needs to be in the *current* directory. Is that the case?

Comment: @g00se The server.jar is in the same directory as the batch script, but not the same directory as the java application running the batch script

Comment: OK, so you need to do some research into what 'current directory' means, but for the moment, remove doubt by replacing all your relative paths with absolute ones (those would be from the drive letter to the file name inclusive)

Comment: @g00se I swapped out the path to an absolute one (for the record, still issue occurs, but pretty sure the point of that specifically wasn't to fix the issue overall)

I tried looking into 'current directory', and it explains it as "current working directory or folder" with some examples. And from that, I feel like my answer would still be that the batch file is in the same directory as server.jar, but that the application executing the batch is *not* in the same directory as the jarfile. But if I still got current directory wrong, then I'm not sure what to answer on that, I'm sorry.

Comment: *I swapped out the path* "The" path? I mean *all* paths

Comment: @g00se I only have the path to the start script, or am I completely wrong? In the snippet of code I run for each test, the only path I can think of is that.

I changed `getAbsolutePath()` to `getCanonicalPath()`, which when I print it out gives me the absolute path

Comment: Ok please post new script in your q and       value of startScript

Comment: @g00se I updated the post with the content of the batch file. The value of `startScript` is `..\prison-spawn-2\start.bat` and the value of the absolute path used where the command text is written is `C:\Users\{MYUSER}\Desktop\{PROJECTNAME_FOLDER}\Network\prison-spawn-2\start.bat`

Comment: Ok you need to reread my comments more carefully, in particular about *drive letters*. Nearly all your paths are *still* relative

Comment: @g00se I now also swapped out the startScript file to be the absolute path, so when I print those 2 values shown above, they now both show the same (being the longer message of the 2 I showed in the message above)

If that is not what you had in mind, then I must admit to not knowing what you mean by swapping all files to absolute

Comment: No visible difference to the path inside the batch file that was there originally...PLUS the code shows you assigning a *relative* path to 'startScript' even now (!)

Comment: @g00se If you look at the code in the post now, is that what you mean?

Comment: What's the point of having a shell script at all here? Why not have your Java code directly start the other jar? You're asking us to help troubleshoot moving pieces that don't need to exist in the first place.

Comment: ...yes, you say you've shown us an error, but if you ask us how to fix that error then we'll be better able to get somewhere useful. It's better to fix the simple thing than to ask a question about how to do a different, more complex, more failure-prone, less-portable thing.

Comment: No change in the script. @CharlesDuffy I'm kind of hoping there are further things not shown ;)

Comment: @g00se, I'm not sure that inference is founded, insofar as the OP says they _tried_ directly invoking the jar with ProcessBuilder and failed (and so fell back to trying to start a script -- "fixing" a broken system by replacing it with a more-complicated, still-broken system).

Comment: I'm also hoping those path elements in curly braces are not real

Comment: @g00se To ease your mind, no those paths in curly braces are not real, hopefully you can sleep a bit better now. I really am trying my best here, but apparently my best in *this case* didn't make the cut.
I do appreciate the help you've given so far, but I'll try to continue on my own using the resources already available to me if that's better

Comment: Before you go, put an absolute path inside your batch file and you might get a different result

Comment: @g00se Alright will do, thank you

Comment: Just to remove all doubt, that means it will start with a drive letter